# Windows still thinks profiles are mandatory even when they are not

Tags: windows-xp, windows-2000, user-profile

A couple of weeks ago, we experimented with mandatory profiles for users, but due to some issues with one piece of software, we had to revert back to roaming profiles.

However, even though the `ntuser` file is now a `.dat`, not a `.man`, the local computers still list the users profile as `Mandatory` (when I right click 'My Computer', click 'Advanced' and then click 'Users...'). This is happening in Windows 2000 and Windows XP, and the Active Directory is located on a Windows Server 2003 machine.

The effect of this is that it takes a very long time for users to log on (usually 20-25 minutes), before a Windows Script Host error is thrown -

[image: Windows Script Host error]

Consequently, I am having to log on to each computer as a local admin and delete the users local copy of their profile so that it is recreated correctly as `Roaming` when they next log on.

Does anyone know of a less time-consuming way of fixing this problem? Thanks.